# mongoid query problem

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to achieve the equivalent of this in mongoid (mongoid.org ORM):

```
 select * from parents 
 inner join children
 on parents.id = children.parent_id
 where children.created_at <= some_timestamp
```

Parent embeds a child, A child belongs to a parent

I have no issues up to this point: Parent.where(:child.exists => true), but I have no idea how I am supposed to do the equivalent of 'child.created_at'.lt => some_timestamp (Illegal to use a method on strings.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoid uses UTC Timestamps internally, to work with a date in a query you can do the following:

```
:'child.created_at'.lt => Time.now.midnight.utc
```

Comment: Apparently something along the lines of this: Parent.where(:child.exists => true, 'child.created_at'.lt => Time.now.midnight.utc) won't work, since its not possible to call #lt on a string. Symbols won't cut it too, because a :child.created_at dot '.' in there is illegal. Any ideas?

Comment: Yep, thanks. Or alternatively :'child.creater_at'.lt. The tip about timestamps was useful as well as I just had to change it:)